# Apache rewrite query string (checkbox array)

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How is it possible to rewrite the query string like:

```
test.php?cat1[]=18&cat1[]=687&xxx[]=5&xxx[]=3&xxx[]=1&yyy[]=6
```

to

```
test.php?cat1=18,687,5&xxx=3,1&yyy=6
```

Note that the parameters (name and value pairs) are generated dynamically.

Comment: It’s absolutely possible. But I wouldn’t do it with mod_rewrite but with PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a short php script that creates the query string that you want. It's best not to do this part using mod_rewrite, because it's simply outside of that scope:

```
<?php

$ret = "";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
  if(is_array($val)) {
    // Create the comma separated string
    $value = $val[0];
    $length = count($val);
    for($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $value .= ',' . $val[$i];
    }
    $ret .= "$key=$value&";
  } else {
    $ret .= "$key=$val&";
  }
}

// Remove last '&'
$ret = substr($ret , 0, strlen($ret)-1);

// Redirect the browser
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved');
header("Location: /test.php?" . $ret);

?>
```

If you save that script as `/rewrite.php`, for example, then you can include these rules in the .htaccess file to reroute requests with query strings containing arrays to `/rewrite.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \[\]
RewriteRule ^test.php /rewrite.php [L,QSA]
```

Then the rewrite.php script will rewrite the query string and redirect the browser with the concatenated query string.

Comment: In my context I'm using WordPress, and the "test.php" in your example is a page named "advanced-search" (which is a pretty permalink already re-written by .htaccess) located @ "http://root/wordpress/advanced-search/"; queries appear as so: "http://root/wordpress/advanced-search/…; Are there any adjustments I need to make to your script to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: What do the queries look like? That link doesn't have anything after /advanced-search/. You'd probably want to change rewriting to /wordpress/advanced-search/ to /rewrite.php (or whatever you want to name it), then at the bottom of rewrite.php, use `pring(get_file_contents("http://your-host/wordpress/advanced-search?$ret"));` instead of redirecting the browser with `header()`

Comment: the queries look like: 10.0.1.4:8888[slash]wordpress[slash]advanced-search[slash]?property_type[]=loft&property_type[]=residential

Comment: so instead of rewriting the pretty premalink URL to `/wordpress/advanced-search`, write to `/rewrite.php` (or whatever you name that script) and instead of using the 2 header lines to redirect the browser, use what I suggested in my previous comment to load the page and output the result.

Comment: so the form HTML should look like: <form name="search" action="rewrite.php" method="GET"> ?

Comment: Or alternatively, you can modify the code so the $_GET array gets rebuilt so the comma separated values get stored, and you can stick that at the top of your advanced-search script.

Answer (score 3):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/apache-rewrite-query-string-checkbox-array/

```
if (preg_match('/[\][]/',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  foreach ($_GET as $key => &$val) {
    $_GET[$key] = is_array($val) ? implode(',', $val) : $val;
  }
  header('Location: test.php?'.rawurldecode(http_build_query(array_filter($_GET))));
}
```

Comment: Consider `'/[\][]/'` and only assigning to `$_GET[$key]` if you change it; you could even have `foreach ($_GET as $key => &$val)` and assign directly to `$val`, so the array is not copied. Otherwise, well done (+1).

Comment: @PointedEars: nice points, tnx ;-) i have also added something to strip empty val just in case. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

test.php?cat1=18,687,5&xxx=3,1&yyy=6

try to insert this function before your code:

```
url_parsestring2array(& $_GET);

function url_parsestring2array($args)
{
    if (empty($args) || !is_array($args) || !$args) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
        $tmp = explode(',', $val);
        if (count($tmp) > 1) {
            $args[$key] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($_GET);
```

will print

> array(3) { ["cat1"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "18" [1]=> string(3)
>   "687" [2]=> string(1) "5" } ["xxx"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3"
>   [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["yyy"]=> string(1) "6" }

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to do this transformation without modifying the code.

In the httpd.conf (in my **VirtualHost** section) I define a rewrite map:

```
RewriteMap programmap prg:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/chg.php
```

Then in the .htaccess I set the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(script.php) $1?${programmap:%1} [L]
```

$1 stand for first "()" in RewriteRule

%1 stand for first "()" in RewriteCond

Then I write this script "*/var/www/localhost/htdocs/chg.php*" (in PHP but can be in C, Perl, or whatelse):

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php
$pos1 =  2;
$pos2 =  $pos1 + 1;
$reg = '/(([a-z0-9_]+)\[\]=([^&]*))/';
while(true){
        $res=array();
        $buff = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        if(feof(STDIN)){
                break;
        }
        $r = preg_match_all($reg, $buff, $match,PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if($r){
                foreach($match as $row){
                        if(!isset($res[$row[$pos1]])){
                                $res[$row[$pos1]] = $row[$pos1]."=".$row[$pos2];
                        } else {
                                $res[$row[$pos1]] .= ",".$row[$pos2];
                        }
                }
                $out=join('&',$res);
        } else {
                $out=$buff;
        }
        echo "$out\n";
}
```